# Android Send file to Server Permission Denied Error

Tags: php, android-studio, retrofit

I m getting Permission Denied Error whenever I click the upload button The Retrofit Call Responses with the onFailure method and Toast the image path of the android device and says Permission Denied

//Here is the upload method from where the image will send to server
private static Context context;

```
public static void uploadImage(String filePath, Context c){
    context = c;
    ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    File file = new File(filePath);
    //image part convert the image to MultipartBody
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),file);
    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file",file.getName(),requestBody);
   // end oof image part
    Log.d("Checking : ","api");

    Call<Response> call = apiInterface.uploadImage(body,"Bangladesh");

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, retrofit2.Response<Response> response) {

            if(response.body() != null){
                Log.d("Checking : ","6");
               /* Logger.d("Response code " + response.code() +
                        " Response Message: " + response.getMessage());*/
                Toast.makeText(context,response.body().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Checking : ","5");
            Toast.makeText(context,t.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });


}
```

//Here is the Server Code with PHP

```
 require_once("connect.php");

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
     $location = "img/";
     chmod($location, 0755);

     $target_file = $location.basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
     $name = $_POST['name'];
      $response = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.');
     
     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)){
         
        $response = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Hello, Your image is uploaded successfully!');

     } 
    
 }
    
 else{
        
     $response = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.');
     
}
echo json_encode($response);
```